# paypal subscriptions and unexpected sandbox events

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

We have implemented paypal subscriptions and have been testing them in the sandbox for about 2 months. In out IPN transactions, there are several events that we see that are unexpected:

- the occasional '`subscr_failed`'
- the even worse '`recurring_payment_suspended_due_to_max_failed_payment`'

Some of our test sessions were for subscriptions recurring daily, some weekly, and some monthly.

Neither of the two events above were caused by us in the sandbox account. 
Can anyone tell me where these come from, any why they occur in the sandbox? I am afraid to go live if the behaviour can have randon events like this.

Comment: You're going to get these in live running. CC payments will fail. You should be grateful the sandbox gave you these events to exercise your code that handles them.

Comment: Do you have any other PayPal subscription buttons or recurring profiles hooked up to this account that would be triggering IPNs?  What's strange is that the subscr_failed IPN would be triggered from PayPal Standard Subscription button, but the recurring_payment_suspended_due_to_max_failed_payment would come from a profile created using the actual recurring payments API, and then that's only triggered after you would get 3 recurring_payment_failed IPNs on re-attempts 5 days apart.

Comment: While I agree with @EJP with respect to being grateful that the sandbox generates these events, I would have thought that it won't generate them on its own without any intervention on our part.

Comment: I have a number of clients (fake) with subscriptions running in the sandbox at the same time, but they are all separate with separate subscriber ids. I have looked through the logs, and haven't really been able to associate the "recurring" messages with three failed attempts, especially since the first one I got while testing still had a live subscription which wouldn't have been the case if I had received any failures. I was testing 'daily' subscriptions and the subscription would not have been extended on the first failure.